# Full type support for multiple Angular pipe arguments

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to have full type support for all arguments which are passed to a custom angular-pipe. Given following pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'alphabetic'
})
export class AlphabeticPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T, K extends keyof T>(values: Array<T>, ...fieldAccessors: K[]): Array<T> {
    // not relevant
  }
}
```

My IDE however only shows me support for the first argument (which is a key of the generic object):
[image]
For the next argument I only see the key which is already used but I want to have the full list, like in the previous picture

[image]

How to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

is that a semicolon `:` in the second screen?

You should use a comma `,` to pass the values for `...fieldAccessors: K[]`.

Comment: Yes it is a colon (:). That is the syntax to pass additional arguments to a pipe. However your comment made me think about an alternative solution